# How to avoid calling the Reader constructor of step 2 before step 1 is completed?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Reader1 reads from a .csv file, Processor1 generates a different output, and Writer1 stores it in the RECORD table, but also stores the file in the FILE table with an autogenerated ID as the primary key.

Reader2 has to retrieve the output from the RECORD table, but I have to indicate the file ID when I do the query in the constructor of Reader2. The problem is, as Reader2 has @Bean annotation, the constructor is called before step 1 is completed, and I don't know the ID because it hasn't been stored yet.

Is there a way to call the constructor of Reader2 after the step 1 is completed?

Answer (score 1):

If you expose the reader as a bean, you can mark it with the annotation `@StepScope`.

The reader bean will then not have the default scope of singleton, instead it will be created newly with every start of a step. In particular, its constructor will only be called after the respective step has started.